# can state have dynamic name ? like state_1, state_2, state_3 until state_x , how to implement this in react native?

Tags: react-native

can state have dynamic name ? like state_1, state_2, state_3 until state_x , how to implement this in react native?

i want to make react-native-display Display have different state on every Display. thank you

state have dynamic name like state_1, state_2, state_3 until state_x

Comment: yes, you can do this through a loop but would not recommend it, rather use one state who's value is an array `const [stateValue,setState] = useState([]);` then  `let newValue = stateValue[] = 'new data';` then `setState(newValue);`

Comment: Use objects.  They were made for storing data under custom names.